# How to retrieve a hidden value from Material UI Autocomplete Option?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a search bar that retrieves names from our database but since multiple users can have the same name (we distinguish by a uid field), I want it so that clicking on one of these options would get me the associated uid field so that I can then redirect the page to the one associated with their uid, etc.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

`

```
const Search = (props) => {

// profiles should be an array (of Profile objects)
// Profile objects have format {uid: , name:, location: , img: , occupation: }
const [profiles, setProfiles] = useState([]);
const classes = props.classes;

const handleChange = async (event) => {
    const name = event.target.value;
    if (name.length > 0) {
        const result = await searchForProfiles(name);
        setProfiles(result);
        if (result.length > 0) {
            console.trace(result);
        }
    }

};
return (
    <div className={classes.search}>
        <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
            <SearchIcon />
        </div>
        <Autocomplete
            freeSolo
            id="free-solo-2-demo"
            disableClearable
            options={profiles}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
            renderInput={params => (
                <InputBase
                    {...params}
                    placeholder="Search…"
                    onKeyPress={event => {
                        handleChange(event);
                    }}
                    classes={{
                        root: classes.inputRoot,
                        input: classes.inputInput,
                    }}
                    InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: 'search' }}
                />
            )}
        />
    </div>

)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [API Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) the `onChange` callback provides the `event` and the `value`.  And the value will be the object provided to the `options` property.  So to capture the full profile object that is selected when the `Autocomplete` value changes, you should be able to do the following:

```
const handleSelected(event, value){
  const uid = value.uid;   //value is the profile object
  //...do what you want with the UID
}
```

Then in your `Autocomplete`, just handle the `onChange` event.

```
<Autocomplete options={profiles} onChange={handleSelect} ...otherProps />
```